# Speeding the search for amicable numbers

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, code-request

The following text is from [Problem 21 - Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21) :

> Let $d(n)$ be defined as the sum of proper divisors of $n$ (numbers less than n which divide evenly into $n$).
>   If $d(a) = b$ and $d(b) = a$, where $a ≠ b$, then $a$ and $b$ are an amicable pair and each of $a$ and $b$ are called amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of $220$ are $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $10$, $11$, $20$, $22$, $44$, $55$ and $110$; therefore $d(220) = 284$. The proper divisors of $284$ are $1$, $2$, $4$, $71$ and $142$; so $d(284) = 220$.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under $10000$.

The fastest *Mathematica* snippet I came up with uses the characterization of amicable numbers as proper involutive points for the divisor sum function:

```
DSum[n_]:=DivisorSigma[1,n]-n
AmicableCandidates=Select[Range[10000], DSum[DSum[#]]==# &];
AmicableNumbers=Select[AmicableCandidates, DSum[#]!=# &];
Sum[AmicableNumbers[[i]], {i,1,Length[AmicableNumbers]}]
```

Timing this yields 0.09375s on my machine.

1. Can this code be improved?
2. What are some other efficient ways to compute the sum of all amicable numbers under $10000$?

Answer (score 2):

Instant speedup:  Change the last line to:

```
Total[AmicableNumbers]
```

Also try this:

```
DSum[n_]:=DivisorSigma[1,n]-n;
Total@Select[Range[10000], (DSum[DSum[#]]==# && DSum[#]!=#) &]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [`DivisorSigma`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DivisorSigma) is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable), one can use a vectorized approach:

```
amicable[list_] := Module[{f1, f2},
    f1 = DivisorSigma[1, list] - list;
    f2 = DivisorSigma[1, f1] - f1;
    Pick[list, Unitize[f1-list]BitXor[Unitize[f2-list], 1], 1]
]
amicable[Range[2,10^4]] //Total //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.045, 31626}

I don't include 1 because `DivisorSigma[1, 1]  - 1` is 0, and `DivisorSigma[1, 0]` is not defined. Hence the output of `f2` becomes unpacked when 1 is included in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just for another way:

```
f[n_] := DivisorSigma[1, n] - n;
g[n_] := NestList[f, n, 2]
Total[Cases[g /@ Range[2, 10000], {i_, j_, i_} /; i!= j]][[1]] // 
RepeatedTiming
```

yields:

```
{0.11, 31626}
```